# Want to generalize the python script for three excel format(.xlsx) / (.xlsm) / (.xls) without doing manually

Tags: python, excel, if-statement

Written a code for converting each each excel sheet into different csv file. But the problem is that the way I have written the code can work only for one format. See this if else statement.

```
if (".xlsx" in str(path_xlsx).lower()) and path_xlsx.is_file():
    xlsx_files = [Path(path_xlsx)]
else:
    xlsx_files = list(Path(path_xlsx).glob("*.xlsx"))
```

Above current if-else statement work for only .xlsx file. But If I want to do for .xlsm format I need to change if-else statement.

```
if (".xlsm" in str(path_xlsm).lower()) and path_xlsm.is_file():
    xlsm_files = [Path(path_xlsm)]
else:
    xlsm_files = list(Path(path_xlsm).glob("*.xlsm"))
```

**Is there any way we can tweak/automate this code that it works for these three excel format(.xls/.xlsm/.xlsx) without changing manually over the code for different excel format.**

```
from pathlib import Path
import time
import parser
import argparse
import pandas as pd
import os
import warnings
 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Process some integers.")
 
parser.add_argument("path", help="define the directory to folder/file")
parser.add_argument("--verbose", help="display processing information")
 
start = time.time()
 
 
def main(path_xlsx, verbose):
    if (".xlsx" in str(path_xlsx).lower()) and path_xlsx.is_file():
        xlsx_files = [Path(path_xlsx)]
    else:
        xlsx_files = list(Path(path_xlsx).glob("*.xlsx"))    
  
 
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for fn in xlsx_files:
        all_dfs = pd.read_excel(fn, sheet_name=None)
        for sheet_name, df in all_dfs.items():
            df = df.assign(DataSource=Path(fn.name))
            x=os.path.splitext(fn.name)[0]
            path=r'Output'
            df.to_csv(os.path.join(path,f'{sheet_name}+{x}.csv'),index=False)            
         
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    path = Path(args.path)
    verbose = args.verbose
    main(path, verbose)  #Calling Main Function
    print("Processed time:", time.time() - start)  #Total Time
```

**Remember: I am running this code through batch script so any excel file format in the folder should be converted into different excel .csv file. In a folder 5 to 6 files are present with three excel extension (.xlsx/.xlsm/.xls) are present.**

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely clear what your issue is. The following will iterate all three types of Excel files. I assume that `pandas` can handle the conversion of each type with no issue. If you have both a `file.xlsx` and a `file.xlsm` with the same sheet names, for example, I imagine they would both convert to the same `csv` file name(s) with one overlaying the other. You should be able to figure out a way of handling that if such a possibility exists.

```py
from itertools import chain
import re
​
​
if re.search(r"\.xls[xm]?$", str(path_xlsx).lower()) and path_xlsx.is_file():
    xlsx_files = [Path(path_xlsx)]
else:
    xlsx_files = list(chain(Path(path_xlsx).glob("*.xls"), Path(path_xlsx).glob("*.xlsx"), Path(path_xlsx).glob("*.xlsm")))
```

**Note**

But there is really no need to first convert `xlsx_files` to be a `list` since you will be iterating the results of `chain` (or `glob` in your original code) with `for fn in xlsx_files:`. It is both wasteful of time and space. So:

```py
from itertools import chain
import re


if re.search(r"\.xls[xm]?$", str(path_xlsx).lower()) and path_xlsx.is_file():
    xlsx_files = [Path(path_xlsx)]
else:
    xlsx_files = chain(Path(path_xlsx).glob("*.xls"), Path(path_xlsx).glob("*.xlsx"), Path(path_xlsx).glob("*.xlsm"))
```